# Complex Rank and Real Rank of a matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Given a matrix $X$, one can calculate its rank by finding the number of non-zero eigenvalues. How does the aforementioned notion of rank relate to complex or real rank of $X$? It would be nice to have an example where the real and complex ranks of a matrix are different.

Answer (score 2):

For a matrix with real entries, its rank over $\Bbb C$ is the same as over $\Bbb R$, and equals to the number of nonzero *complex* eigenvalues (with multiplicity).

Note that this statement holds only over an *algebraically closed* field, so that the characteristic polynomial can be factored as $\prod_j(X-\lambda_j)$.

For example, the matrix $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$ has *no real eigenvalues*, though its rank is $2$.

For matrices with complex entries, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Many thanks. This was helpful.

Comment: Hello @Berci, is there a proof that the rank over $\mathbb{C}$ is same as over $\mathbb{R}$? It would be great to look at a proof of this!